# How to get headings at top of the List of figure and list of table

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing my report. I am using following codes.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chngcntr,tocloft}
\counterwithin*{figure}{section}
\counterwithin*{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin*{figure}{subsubsection}

\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{2em}


\renewcommand{\thefigure}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0
    \thechapter.\arabic{figure}%
  \else  
    \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
       \thesection.\arabic{figure}%
    \else
       \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
         \thesubsection.\arabic{figure}%
       \else
         \thesubsubsection.\arabic{figure}%
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{Intro}
\section{A section}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{section.figure}
\end{figure}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{subsection.figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{subsection.figure}
\end{figure}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{subsubsection.figure}
\end{figure}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{subsection.figure}
\end{figure}
\section{A section}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{section.figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is giving me output like this:
[image]
 But i want it like this:
[image]
How to get it. It should be applicable to both list of figure and list of tables

Answer (score 2):

Not the full solution so far -- the `dots` have to disappear still. I am trying to figure this out.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\counterwithin*{figure}{section}
\counterwithin*{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin*{figure}{subsubsection}

\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{2em}


\renewcommand{\thefigure}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0
    \thechapter.\arabic{figure}%
  \else  
    \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
       \thesection.\arabic{figure}%
    \else
       \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
         \thesubsection.\arabic{figure}%
       \else
         \thesubsubsection.\arabic{figure}%
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
}

\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\widthof{figurename}}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\widthof{tablename}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{figure}{\numberline{\bfseries \figurename}\textbf{Illustration}}{\textbf{Page}}}
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{figure}{\numberline{\bfseries \tablename}\textbf{Description}}{\textbf{Page}}}
\listoftables
\chapter{Intro}
\section{A section}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{section.figure}
\end{figure}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{subsection.figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{subsection.figure}
\end{figure}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{subsubsection.figure}
\end{figure}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{subsection.figure}
\end{figure}
\section{A section}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{section.figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\caption{Another table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** Improved version

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\counterwithin*{figure}{section}
\counterwithin*{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin*{figure}{subsubsection}

\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{2em}


\renewcommand{\thefigure}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0
    \thechapter.\arabic{figure}%
  \else  
    \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
       \thesection.\arabic{figure}%
    \else
       \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
         \thesubsection.\arabic{figure}%
       \else
         \thesubsubsection.\arabic{figure}%
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\let\@origpnumwidth\@pnumwidth
\let\@newdottedtocline\@dottedtocline%



\xpatchcmd{\@newdottedtocline}{%
  \hbox{.}%
}{%
  \hbox{}% Drop the dots
}{}{}

\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{25pt}%

\newcommand*\l@figureheading{\@newdottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{\cftfignumwidth}}
\newcommand*\l@tableheading{\@newdottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{\cfttabnumwidth}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\makeatletter
\listoffigures
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\widthof{figurename}}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\widthof{tablename}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{figureheading}{\numberline{\bfseries \figurename}\textbf{Illustration}}{\textbf{Page}}}
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{tableheading}{\numberline{\bfseries \tablename}\textbf{Description}}{\textbf{Page}}}

\listoftables
\let\@pnumwidth\@origpnumwidth
\makeatother


\chapter{Intro}
\section{A section}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{section.figure}
\end{figure}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{subsection.figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{subsection.figure}
\end{figure}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{subsubsection.figure}
\end{figure}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{subsection.figure}
\end{figure}
\section{A section}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{section.figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\caption{Another table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]